# Scan (jpg) of a table: list of tables or list of figures?

Tags: floats

I have a scan (jpg) of a table from a book, and I want to use it in my own work.
It shows position and name of awardees of a type design prize, the names of their types, and the typefaces themselves:

[image: Luo Shubao 罗树宝, 20 shiji houbanqi de yinshua ziti ２０世纪后半期的印刷字体, in Yinshua zazhi 220/7 (2004): 91.]

I cannot myself produce it in LaTeX, because I do not have access to the (metal) type.

I use a `figure` environment and `includegraphics` to load the picture, and accordingly, it goes into the list of figures.
Since, however, this actually shows a table, readers might look for it in the list of tables.

Do you consider this a table or a figure?
If it’s a table: how do I get it into the list of tables instead? Should I simply use a table environment instead of a figure environment?

Comment: I don't think this is a question to be asked on tex.se but more suitable somewhere dedicated to writing papers.

Comment: Interesting question (although indeed maybe a bit off-topic). I would say it is a figure, i.e., a figure showing a table, rather than being a 'real' table - but you could argue otherwise. In any case, if you want to use it as a table then indeed you can just use a `table` environment with an `\includegraphics` inside.

Comment: It is a table, use the table environment.